# Cannot mount USB after unsafe eject

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, mount, eject

I have a 16GB usb flash drive and I made it bootable to install Linux Mint.
But for some reason, I couldn't install and did an unsafe eject.

Now, I cannot mount the drive, neither on Windows nor Linux.

If I run `'sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb'`, following shows,

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15267 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4c66d349

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           0     1982463      991232   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
```

Is my flash drive dead? How can I make it work again?

Comment: Always run fdisk on the raw device - so `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. The file system may just need to be checked. If the drive has been partitioned, then you should run fsck on the partitions. This may get the drive to a point of being usable without needing to reinitialize it

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I updated my post. As you can tell, I am new with these stuffs. I never used fsck. Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: you can try `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1` to check the file system

Comment: I am getting the following ...
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.iso9660: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.iso9660 for /dev/sdb1

Comment: it sounds like the partition that was created is a cdrom-style file system. I've added an answer for reinitializing the device so that it can be used again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you have a few options.

You can erase the content of the device and start again:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb
sudo hdparm -z /dev/sdb
mkdir /tmp/x
sudo mount /dev/sdb /tmp/x
```

You can try checking the file system on `/dev/sdb1`, but based on comments from the op, it looks like it's a cdrom image, so it's read-only.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have unmounted the failing disk `/dev/sd[X]` from its directory and run

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd[X] bs=512 count=1`

This filled it with binary zeros at a low level of formatting.

Then I could plug it in again and reformat it with GParted, starting again from the partition table and then with the file system of choice.