# What damages can occur if flash drives are not safetly removed?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, security, usb-flash-drive

What damages can occur to my computer or my flash drive such as pendrive if I don't safety remove it before plugging it out after any read or write operation on my pendrive also if  there is no read or write operation and then if I plug out my pendrive, then what damage can occur

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please. This is the reason you have down votes, it is a good question without research effort on your part.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my level best to do some research, both theoretically and practically. I'm new here and the down votes scares me a bit to ask a question

Comment: All you have to do is post some research you have done in your question, this is the only way we know you have at least tried to solve it before asking here, this is how you get up votes.....you can use the edit text button under your tags to add some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unplug a flashdrive during a write operation, the file will become damaged and you lose its contents. Next time you open it, it'll give you an error.

If the write operation occurs on the file table itself, it may cause the flashdrive to become labelled as empty telling you that you need to format the drive.

Comment: I had one write lock on me ejecting it during a write, another just became totally useless after that, no OS would even recognize it was plugged in, tossed it.

Answer (score 1):

For unplugging, the OS will sync the data during the unmount operation. Thus, if the disk is unmounted (assuming you in fact do have full hardware support) you can power off the disk then unplug it without risk of data loss or corruption.

A partition map can be corrupted by an incomplete write operation. If it was just the partition table that was corrupted, a good data recovery application should be able to get things back.

PS:
[Bad scenario: Cannot mount USB after unsafe eject](https://superuser.com/questions/546486/cannot-mount-usb-after-unsafe-eject)

Comment: Thanks, this was a bit helpful. And sorry an amateur question. I'm new here.